# How to assign multiple ids to one row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Let's say we have a table with these records of tags:

```
Category   ID

apples     1
orange     2
```

And then we have another table with a row

```
Data catID
...    1
```

With this setup we can retrieve this row only in apples page, what is the proper way to assign both apples & orange to that row? Would I need to change `catID` field from integer to varchar and just add the second id so the value will be `1,2` and then edit the query to something like:

```
 select * from table where catID LIKE '%1%' 
 select * from table where catID LIKE '%2%'
```

instead of

```
  select * from table where catID='1'
  select * from table where catID='2'
```

I'm not sure if this is the proper way? Could someone tell how you do it? Basically, I don't want to duplicate the whole row, just to add another id to it.

Comment: Google for "many to many" relations

Comment: Google 'junction table'. Never, ever, ever, put comma separated data in a database, or I will eat your kitten.

Comment: I hope you don't really have a table named `table`...

Comment: @leonbloy why not, I've seen less descriptive names being used in databases :P

Comment: leonbloy, obviously i dont. and i dont have apples with oranges either :P

Comment: so how would a query look? any examples

Comment: Just join like in any other query, just with another table included.

Comment: I think you didnt get what I meant. I dont need to select both ids at the same time. I need to select them separately from 2 different pages. But the row now contains only one id. I could duplicate the row and put id 2 instead of 1, but thats a waste.

Comment: No that's not a waste. That's how relational database works.

Comment: Alexandre P. Levasseur, so I have to duplicate a row with 30 fields just to assign another id to it??

Comment: Exactly. If you have frequent groups, however, you may want to create another table to hold these groups to avoid repetition. I would only do it if you have groups that have a high occurence. This would add another table so you have to weight the redundancy vs the speed cost of adding another join.

Comment: Why do you want to put into one row multiple IDs? Could you give us your exact scenario or context you want to do?

Comment: Edper, imagine you have on one image apples and oranges or Audi & Mercedes. So When you visit mercedes page it pulls that record, and also on audi page it pulls the same record. Any ideas except duplicating the row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already suggested, many-to-many relationship is represented in the physical model by a junction table. I'll do the leg work and illustrate that for you:

[image]

The CATEGORY_ITEM is the junction table. It has a composite PK consisting of FKs migrated from the other two tables. Example data...

**CATEGORY:**

```
CATEGORY_ID CATEGORY
----------- --------
1           Apple
2           Orange
```

**ITEM:**

```
ITEM_ID     NAME
-------     ----
1           Foo
2           Bar
```

**CATEGORY_ITEM:**

```
CATEGORY_ID ITEM_ID
----------- -------
1           1
2           1
1           2
```

The above means: *"Foo is both Apple and Orange, Bar is only Apple"*.

The PK ensures any given combination of category and item cannot exist more than once. The category is either connected to the item of isn't - it cannot be connected multiple times.

Since you primarily want to search for items of given category, the order of fields in the PK is {CATEGORY_ID, ITEM_ID} so the underlying index can satisfy that query. The exact explanation why is beyond this scope - if you are interested I warmly recommend reading [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

And since [InnoDB uses clustering](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), this will also store items belonging to the same category physically close together, which may be rather beneficial for I/O of the query above.

*(If you wanted to query for categories of the given item, you'd need to flip the order of fields in the index.)*

Comment: so that requires creating 3rd table...and then we use joins in queries? I thought there is a simple way. Thanks for a solid answer.

Comment: Branko, can I add a 3rd PK field to `CATEGORY_ITEM` and have combination of three unique fields?

Comment: @BeavisIsCool Depends on what you want to accomplish. The third PK field would allow you to have multiple rows containing the same combination of the other two fields.

Comment: I see, could you post an example of proper join query too, is it left, inner or just join ? thanks

Comment: @BeavisIsCool Again, depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: no problems, I figured it out already with LEFT join. thanks again and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you realized that two ids indexing one row is a typical application of bidirectional relationship management in a real project? We need a smarter solution in DB rather than the two rows/junction table solution. In MongoDB, you could make `"low_id:hight_id"` as field `"_id"` and field `"uids_low_high"`, and indexing the `"uids_low_high"` for `"$in:[$id]"` search.